# How to add a file to git repository if it shows it's contents are identical?

Tags: android, git

I am given an image file with extension SPR and have to add it to Android Application. When I replaced the file on Android Studio, I can see the changed ICON on Android Device. But, Git says files are Identical and not showing file to add. Its names are similar and I can't change it. Git shows its contents in UTF-8 are identical. How do I add this file to repository?

I tried:

```
git add --force E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw\quick_panel_icon_spr_wfc.spr

git add --update E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw\quick_panel_icon_spr_wfc.spr

git add --refresh E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw\quick_panel_icon_spr_wfc.spr

git diff  E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw\quick_panel_icon_spr_wfc.spr

git diff --text  E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw\quick_panel_icon_spr_wfc.spr
```

I expect to add new file to repository.

Comment: If the contents of the file is identical (talking about **a single file**, not two files with the same content), git won't allow you to "add" it. Even if it did (which it won't), at the moment of committing the file, it will be the same object, to git, there is no change... so if you do a diff or log with the new revision, it will never show up.

Comment: You can try deleting the file, commit, then adding it in another commit. Still, I am surprised git is not making the difference between your two files.

Comment: When I add a file to second commit and push both. It says empty commit and rejects it.

Comment: Is your *work-tree* located in `E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main\res\raw` (or `E:\UnifiedWfc\src\main` or something along those lines)? That is, what does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` print? What, if any, error message(s) or other output do you get when running these various commands? (See [mcve] and [ask].)